# selecting rows in a kogrid by clicking a button in a column

Tags: javascript, .net, knockout.js

I have kogrid with one column having view button for each row. When I click on View button I need to display a popup with values of that row. How can i extract selected row values in order to pass into popup

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do your kogrid and viewmodel look like? please, add more info, or probably someone will delete your question.

Comment: self.rGridCols = [           
            { field: 'ApplicationNum', displayName: 'Application #', width: '*' }, 
            { field: 'Applicant', displayName: 'Applicant', width: '*' },                     
            { field: "View", displayName: "View", width: '*', cellTemplate: ViewButtonTmpl }
        ];

this.cellTemplates.ViewButtonTmpl = 
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-target="#view-transaction-modal" data-toggle="modal" 
          data-bind=\"click: $parent.getProperty('ApplicationNum') \>View</button>';

Comment: Please, edit the question and include this information there to make it useful for other people, and to raise the chances that someone answers it. There are already two request to close it. You can still save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected value and put it in a property that will be the context of the modal, see the snippet bellow that get the row data and put as a context of modal.

```js
function viewModel() {
  this.currentRowValues = ko.observableArray([]);
  this.gridData = ko.observableArray([{
    name: "Moroni",
    age: 50
  }, {
    name: "Tiancum",
    age: 43
  }, {
    name: "Jacob",
    age: 27
  }, {
    name: "Nephi",
    age: 29
  }, {
    name: "Enos",
    age: 34
  }]);


  this.detailBtnTemplate = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-bind="click: $parent.$userViewModel.setModelContext.bind($parent.$userViewModel,$parent)">Detail </button>'

  this.reconciliationGridOptions = {
    data: this.gridData,
    selectedItems: this.currentRowValues,
    afterSelectionChange: function(selectedRow) {

      return true;
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      displayName: 'Name'
    }, {
      displayName: 'Action',
      cellTemplate: '<button data-bind="click: $parent.$userViewModel.log.bind($parent.$userViewModel,$parent)">Log</button>'
    }, {
      displayName: 'Detail',
      cellTemplate: this.detailBtnTemplate
    }]
  };

  this.message = "binded context";
  this.modalContext = ko.observable();
};
viewModel.prototype.save = function() {
  alert(ko.toJSON(this.currentRowValues()));
};

//Function that will be binded with the row
viewModel.prototype.log = function(rowData) {
  console.log("row data: ", rowData);
  console.log("entity data: ", rowData.entity);
  //Showing the context binded
  alert(this.message);
};
viewModel.prototype.setModelContext = function(rowData) {
  console.log("entity data: ", rowData.entity);
  this.modalContext({name:ko.observable(rowData.entity.name),age: ko.observable(rowData.entity.age)});
};


ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
.gridStyle {
  border: 1px solid rgb(212, 212, 212);
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
.selectedItems {
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.lukej.me/kogrid/2.0.6/KoGrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.lukej.me/kogrid/2.0.6/koGrid.debug.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



<div class="gridStyle" id="reconciliationGrid" data-bind="koGrid: reconciliationGridOptions"></div>

<button data-bind="click: save">Save Example</button>
<br/>
<div class="selectedItems" data-bind="foreach: currentRowValues">
  <span data-bind="text:ko.toJSON($data)"></span>
</div>




<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-bind="with: modalContext">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Detail Person</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <input id="age" type="number" data-bind="value: age" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```